# Erro na chamada de API com python - JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, api

Estou realizando essa chamada em uma API do Mailchimp, porém está retornando um erro no json que não sei como resolver, podem me ajudar??

Meu código:

```
import requests
import psycopg2


key = 'KEY'
url = 
'https://us17.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/ecommerce/stores/id_loja/carts? 
count=10000'
head = {'anystring':KEY}

r = requests.get(url, auth=('user',key))

info = r.json()

print(info)
```

Erro que retorna:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Não tenho familiaridade com a documentação da API do Mailchimp, mas você tem certeza que seu url está correto? Principalmente no trecho `id_loja`: você não deveria substituir aquela parte com algum ID de fato?

Comment: Qual é o retorno da API? Garanto que se você souber a string que a requisição retornou você saberá o que houve de errado.